# Add a user control to a wpf window

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a user control that I've created, however when I go to add it to the XAML in the window, Intellisense doesn't pick it up, and I can't figure out how to add it to the window.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to add a reference inside the window tag. Something like:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YourCustomNamespace.Controls;assembly=YourAssemblyName"
```

(When you add xmlns:controls=" intellisense should kick in to make this bit easier)

Then you can add the control with:

```
<controls:CustomControlClassName ..... />
```

Comment: It's now 2015, and designer still doesn't do this automatically?  **WTF!?!**

Comment: @MartinHarris What should I write in "yourassemblyname"?

Comment: Obviously your assembly name - this is name of the output file (mostly dll). If output dll has name awesome.assembly.dll then "yourassemblyname" is "awesome.assembly".

Comment: VS2013 designer was happier with assembly omitted

Comment: VS2017 now fixes `<CustomControlClassName` by offering a light bulb to add the namespace.  :-)

Comment: How do I know the assemly name

Answer (score 14):

You probably need to add the [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx):

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlTest"
    Title="User Control Test" Height="300" Width="300">
    <local:UserControl1 />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 13):

Make sure there is an namespace definition (`xmlns`) for the namespace your control belong to.

```
xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:YourCustomNamespace.Controls;assembly=YourAssemblyName"
```

```
<myControls:thecontrol/>
```

Comment: +1 for "sometimes intellisense is stupid.". Make sure that the project actually doesn't compile and run, I've lost track of the number of times VS has told me my xmal is invalid when all it needed was a rebuild to make it reconsider.

Comment: @MartinHarris yes! Also, I put my control in a Grid and initially forgot to give it a Grid.Row/Grid.Column assignment and Grid.RowSpan/Grid.ColumnSpan.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I got it to work:

User Control WPF

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.ProcessView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

User Control C#

```
namespace App {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProcessView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProcessView : UserControl // My custom User Control
    {
        public ProcessView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    } }
```

---

MainWindow WPF

```
<Window x:Name="RootWindow" x:Class="App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:App"
        Title="Some Title" Height="350" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing_1" Icon="bouncer.ico">
    <Window.Resources>
        <app:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <app:ProcessView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```